# How to call a bash script from another bash script with parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I want to call xyz.sh script from abc.sh script but xyz.sh takes parameters while running the script. the parameter passed while starting the script is xyz.sh -base onetwo.so how to call the xyz.sh script from abc.sh script so that i also need to pass parameters.

The abc.sh script contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script is about to run  script."
sh ./xyz.sh
echo "This script has finished  script."
```

Here my doubt is how are you passing the parametrs "-base onetwo" while executing to xyz.sh in abc.sh
Note :here onetwo can be any string which varies

Please help to resolve this

Comment: Why don't you just use `./xyz.sh -base onetwo`? Where does the _string which varies_ come from? As an aside, note that `sh ./xyz.sh` will invoke different behaviour than `bash ./xyz.sh` - you should use `bash`, or if the script is executable with `#!/bin/bash` at the start, just `./xyz.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try just like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script is about to run  script."
sh ./xyz.sh param1 param2
echo "This script has finished  script."
```